# Kotlin type interference failed

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I am getting this error here:

`Type inference failed: fun <R : Any!> flatMap(p0: ((Response<ResendOtpResponseDto!>) -> SingleSource<out R!>!)!): Single<R!> cannot be applied to ((Response<ResendOtpResponseDto!>) -> KFunction1<@ParameterName Response<ResendOtpResponseDto>, Single<ResendOtpResponseDto>>)`

I don't know why.

Here is my code where the error is:

[image]

And here is my parseResendOtpResponse:

[image]

Comment: Do `flatMap(this::parseResendOtpResponse)` instead. Brackets indicate a lambda, you want a function reference.

Comment: You are wrapping a function in another function. Use parentheses instead of braces. Since your function is inside a lambda, `this` is referring to the lambda receiver.

Comment: That solve the issue, thank you so much.

Comment: yeah @sidgate, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flatMap` function takes a function reference as the first parameter. `this::parseResendOtpResponse` is a function reference, so you have to pass it in parentheses.

We use curly brace when you want to immediately pass the function body.

```
list.flatMap({it.items}) // lambda within parentheses

list.flatMap(){it.items} // lambda outside parentheses 

list.flatMap {it.items} // lambda without parentheses

val fn: (List<List<...>>) -> List<...> = { it.items }  //lambda
list.flatMap(fn)
```

All above represents same call